# Uncaught TypeError: this.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi this is my (shortcuted) example code:

```
export class SolarSystemInfo {

    constructor() {
        this.test();
    }

    // click on solar system
    clickSolarSystem() {
        $("body").on("click",".hex", function() {
            this.test();
        }); 
    }

    public test () {
        alert('test');
    }

}
```

My problem is, that in constructor is **test** function called right, but in **clickSolarSystem** function after calling *this.test()* I get: ***Uncaught TypeError: this.test is not a function***
How I have to call **test** function in my function inner class?
Thanks

Comment: Using test() without `this` is not working ?

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Comment: @Zooly: That definitely wouldn’t work.

Comment: this.test is out of scope inside jquery

Comment: // click on solar system
    clickSolarSystem() {
       var self = this;
        $("body").on("click",".hex", function() {
            self.test();
        }); 
    }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The context of `this` is lost when the callback function is being executed.
To solve that you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
clickSolarSystem() {
    $("body").on("click",".hex", () => {
        this.test();
    }); 
}
```

Or you can use the [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
clickSolarSystem() {
    $("body").on("click",".hex", function() {
        this.test();
    }).bind(this); 
}
```

Comment: It would probably help to explain what `this` refers to in each context.

Comment: @cdbajorin updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for help:

Comment: arrow function () =>  it works for me